# Background-size:cover and text in an horizontal scrolling page

Tags: html, css, css-position, background-size

I'm trying to make a very simple HTML page with horizontal scrollbar that contains only one big picture (with `background-size:cover`) on the left and a long text with columns on the right of the cover.

I think that my problem is about `position:relative` (with float) and `position:absolute` (with left), but I don't manage to fix it. At the moment, the cover picture is OK, displayed on the top left. But the text is displayed on the bottom right (instead of on the top right of the cover).

Could you please help me ?

Here is the demo showing what I've done : http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/38/

Comment: try to change #cover with absolute position.

Comment: This is OK with Chrome and Safari, but not with FF and IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understanded you corectly, than you need to put text in to your cover id, not in seperate div. However, you can change your cover id position to absolute only, and relative position to your text div.

```
#cover { position:absolute; /* other stuff */ }
```

and

```
#text {  position:relative; /* other stuff */ }


http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/46/
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works ! The two divs are separated because I don't want the text to be placed over the picture, but on the right of it. Anyway, thank you again. :) Here is the result : http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/40/

Comment: It works with Chrome and Safari, but it doesn't work with Firefox and IE, as you can see here : http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/40/
Could you please help me to get this fixed with FF and IE ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't want the text to be over the picture... What I previously got with Chrome and Safari was perfect, visually speaking.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer ! :-) But sorry, I don't want to scroll the columns over the picture. I would like the picture to stay on the left of the columns, and the 2 elements to be scrolling together. This demo http://jsfiddle.net/kz5ch49w/40/ was visually exactly what I would like on Chrome and Safari, but it doesn't work on FF and IE.